# 0 downvotes in 2 weeks, across ~3500 users!

Tags: discussion, participation, culture, voting, down-votes

When examining the stats from 13 October to 3 November, we find that our ~3500 users have ***in total*** only downvoted once (on 15 October) and we went more than 2 weeks without ever downvoting. Thanks for helping us be (what I consider to be) the most welcoming and friendly community on the Stack Exchange network!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I almost down voted this purely for irony

Comment: Haha, the post is about main site downvotes though. Downvotes on meta would be in a separate chart!